# Are even cumulants necessary non-zero infinitely often?

Tags: probability, cumulants

Let $X$ be a random variable with moment generating function $e^{P(t)}$ for a power series $P(t)$. Assume the moment generating function exists in a neighbourhood of 0. Then the cumulant generating function is $P(t)$ whose coefficients give the cumulants.

My question is, is it true for any distribution apart from the Normal that there are infinitely many non-zero even order cumulants?

Comment: Degenerate rvs  are other examples.

Comment: Yes but apart from those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A theorem of J. Marcinkiewicz (
"Sur une propriété de la loi de Gauß",
*Math. Z.* 44 (1939), no. 1, 612–618, cited
by Linnik, Kagan, and Rao, p. 25, or by Luckacs, p. 213; I have not studied the original paper) says that if a cumulant generating function is a polynomial, it is a polynomial of degree at most $2$.  If your $P(t)$ had finitely many even Taylor coefficients, then $P(t)+P(-t)$ would be a polynomial, and hence of degree at most $2$.  But $P(t)+P(-t)$ is the cumulant generating function of the difference $X_1-X_2$ of two iid copies of $X$.  Hence $X_1-X_2$ is normally distributed, and by a theorem of Cramer, so are the summands $X_i$.